# How do I arrange the tabular data into structured text in R?

Tags: r, text, tabular

I am trying to create a text from the tabular data in R. The text should have a specific structure though. See below the exemplary tabular and exemplary text created based on this data for more clarity on what I want to achieve.

Tabular Data:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Project AAA | Information 1 |
| Project AAA | Information 2 |
| Project AAA | Information 3 |
| Project BBB | Information 4 |
| Project CCC | Information 5 |
| Project CCC | Information 6 |

I want to create a text from this table. I want to group the data in column B under data in Column A, a kinda a child-parent relationship. It does not matter whether the text will be available in R and I will have to copy it, or the text is exported as a txt file or something else. Everything works as long as from the tabular structure as above, I can obtain text structured as follows :

Project AAA
-Information 1
-Information 2
-Information 3

Project BBB
-Information 4

Project CCC
-Information 5
-Information 6

Any help or advice is much appreciated!! You are more than welcome to suggest apps outside R too, which could do this magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dplyr, you can concatenate your headers and bullets by using `paste0()` in a few summaries:

```
library(dplyr)

txt <- dat %>% 
  group_by(header = `Column A`) %>% 
  summarize(bullets = paste0("-", `Column B`, collapse = "\n")) %>% 
  summarize(txt = paste0(header, "\n", bullets, collapse = "\n\n")) %>% 
  pull(txt)

cat(txt)
```

```
Project AAA
-Information 1
-Information 2
-Information 3

Project BBB
-Information 4

Project CCC
-Information 5
-Information 6
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much! Works just fine. Now I am exploring options to apply customization (colour, font size, bold...) to the text.

Comment: As HTML tags, or in the R console itself, or something else?